# How to create line extension of a button

Tags: html, css, button, sass, frontend

I would like to ask if this is possible, I'm trying to achieve this design which
has a curve line extension of a button/ or `<a>` tag. my first choice is to export this line image and insert it after the button. but is there any ways of CSS styling that can make this possible,

[image]

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Could be done using a positioned pseudo element, that has a border-bottom and -right set, and a border radius.

Comment: yeah @CBroe, I never thought that it could be possible. I have already tried many times but I guess I need to improve more my CSS skill. hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is possible, I'm just not sure whether it's advisable. Anyway, you can use an absolutely positioned pseudo element but as always with absolute positioning, you have to be careful when it comes to responsiveness. In the example, I'm using quite a lot of magic numbers which I don't really like.

I would probably rather use JavaScript and SVG to make the line properly positioned/sized on all devices.

Anyway, here's a CSS solution:

```css
body {
  padding: 200px 50px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #92701b;
  border-radius: 999px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 21px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 0;
  border: 4px solid #d76f46;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Polyethylene</button>
```

Comment: WOW, @Mihi you make it possible thank you for this very much, this is better than what I am thinking, would you mind if you can share about your solution using javascript? but if this is really helpful to me.

Comment: how about if the straight line is on the bottom? , I tried the height property to negative but it wont work, any idea?

Comment: You're welcome @cdt! I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but adding these attributes to the :after element should do the thing:

```
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 20px);
  z-index: -1;
```

I'll try to post a JS solution later today

Comment: cool i'll try this later @Mihi, I have tried this property earlier to the :after element ""transform: rotate(270deg);"" then it works, I don't know if this is fine but I guess it's not a good practice. maybe your answer is better, I need to try this.

Comment: Thanks, @mihi , looking forward to your JS solution.